# How to create custom ribbon in excel by using vba

Tags: excel, vba

I need to create custom ribbon in excel by using vba. Like this:

[image]

I can do it by using Custom UI Editor for Microsoft Office but I want to know if it can do it by using VBA.

Comment: Yes, it can be done in VBA. But it's not pretty and I would strongly advise against it.

Comment: You'll want to create an excel add-in

Answer (score 0):

According to [Dutch Gemini](https://dutchgemini.wordpress.com/2011/01/20/custom-excel-2007-ribbon-and-vba/), "You cannot create ribbon elements dynamically in VBA." It's possible tools have been created in the 6 years since his article. However, the article does give hints from his experience with the Ribbon and modifying elements using VBA.